# C++ - Function pointer with arbitrary number of args

Tags: c++, function-pointers, argument-passing

I'm trying to make a CPP function that takes a function pointer and an arbitrary number of arguments, adds some coordinates, then calls the function pointer as such:

```
int func_api(void(*fun)(int, int, ...args), ...args) {
    fun(this.x, this.y, args);
}
```

so I can use it as such:

```
int func(int x, int y, int param1, int param2) {
    something;
}

int foo () {
    func_api(p1, p2);
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could use [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template). You might be interested in [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi)

Answer (score 2):

Use a variadic template

```
template <typename Func, typename ... Args>
int func_api(Func fun, Args&&... args)
{
 fun(this->x, this->y, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

You can now call it like this:

```
func_api(func, p1, p2);
```